# CSS3 positioning/Height issue

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

Am working on a project where **am inserting** some code of CSS3 animation onto a website made with a template.

There occurred some problem where the animated items are out of size.

Here's [the website](http://www.planetgmachines.com/test-page/)(Scroll down for the animation)

Here's [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EJX6j/18/) of the animation if anyone wants to check that out.

Some basic code that maybe of use..

**CSS:**

```
#backgroundAnimation{
    color:#3c3c3c;
}

#containerAnimation{
    margin:0 auto;
/*    float : left;*/
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

#innerWrapperAnimation{
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px solid;
    float:none;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    height: auto;   
    background: no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    max-width: 1460px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="containerAnimation">
    <div id="innerWrapperAnimation">
        <div><img class="lightsAnimation" id="light1Animation" alt="" src="http://www.planetgmachines.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Light-1.png" /></div>
        <img class="lightsAnimation" id="light2Animation" alt="" src="http://www.planetgmachines.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Light-2.png" />
        <img class="lightsAnimation" id="cameraFlashAnimation" alt="" src="http://www.planetgmachines.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Camera-Flash.png" />
        <img id="backgroundAnimation" alt="" src="http://www.planetgmachines.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/bg3.png" />
        <img class="boxAnimation" id="goodBox1" alt="" src="http://www.planetgmachines.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Box-1.png" />
        <img class="boxAnimation" id="goodBox2" alt="" src="http://www.planetgmachines.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Box-1.png" />
        <img class="boxAnimation" id="goodBox3" alt="" src="http://www.planetgmachines.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Box-1.png" />
        <img class="boxAnimation" id="goodBox4" alt="" src="http://www.planetgmachines.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Box-1.png" />
        <img class="boxAnimation" id="goodBox5" alt="" src="http://www.planetgmachines.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Box-1.png" />
        <img id="badBox1" alt="" src="http://www.planetgmachines.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Box-2.png" />
        <img id="pistonBase" alt="" src="http://www.planetgmachines.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/piston_base.png" />
        <img id="pistonHead" alt="" src="http://www.planetgmachines.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/piston_head.png" />
        <img id="pistonOutline" alt="" src="http://www.planetgmachines.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/piston_top.png" />
        <div id="waveDisplay"><img id="waveImage" alt="" src="http://www.planetgmachines.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Vital-sign-1.png" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Am pretty bad at css,if someone could help me out by **using the firebug or any other debugger** and point me out **where i need to make the change.** That would be great.

I think its a really small issue for you professionals out there.

**Update: The height of the animated container changes within the website. I think that's the issue.**

Comment: what exactly your issue is? "items are out of size." what do you mean by this?

Comment: You saw the animation? 
Its out of alignment.(Check with fiddle)

Comment: Check my update also..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update is correct.

The `<br>` between your animated elements (boxes) are causing your container height to expand.

If you add the CSS: `#innerWrapperAnimation br { display: none;}`, it addresses your issue (or, just don't include the `<br>` element)

Comment: Btw how did you come across that?

Answer (score 0):

Try either fixing your containerAnimation or innerWrapperAnimation i.e in px in place of % and remove br tag as different browsers take different br space. To create a line space towards bottom : try margin-bottom:in px or padding-bottom:in px whichever suits you.